# How do I get a list of Team Foundation Server Servers available on my PC?

Tags: c#

I need to get Team Foundation Server list programmatically with C#.

This is needed for the `TfsTeamProjectCollection` object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had a scan through the documentation and couldn't find anything useful.  I believe @samy is correct and there is no discovery mechanism.

However if you are running this on a client machine that already has established connections to TFS then there is a history of servers stored in the registry:

Visual Studio 2008 location:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\TeamFoundation\Servers
```

Visual Studio 2010:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\TeamFoundation\Instances\
```

Visual Studio 2012

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\TeamFoundation\Instances\
```

Visual Studio 2013

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\TeamFoundation\Instances\
```

Visual Studio 2015

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\TeamFoundation\Instances\
```

Comment: Or for VS2010, HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\TeamFoundation\Instances

Answer (score 0):

I think the responsibility of keeping track of the servers is your responsibility. There's no discovery options for the servers as far as i know. So you need the uris

Answer (score 0):

For Visual Studio 2012, the location in the registry key is:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\TeamFoundation\Instances\tfs
```

Answer (score 0):

To list all workspaces that "tf workspaces" would return (which includes URI and mapped paths):

```
var allWorkspaceInfos = Workstation.Current.GetAllLocalWorkspaceInfo();
```

To get the TFS workspace containing a particular directory:

```
var workspaceInfo = Workstation.Current.GetLocalWorkspaceInfo(@"C:\Users\joey\tfs");
```

I found this by decompiling TF.exe.  But there is documentation for the [Workstation class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.workstation_methods%28v=vs.120%29.aspx).

These methods return [WorkspaceInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.workspaceinfo%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) objects.  To perform source control operations, you need to connect to the server and get a [Workspace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.workspace%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) object:

```
var collection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(workspaceInfo.ServerUri);
collection.Authenticate();
var server = collection.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
var workspace = server.GetWorkspace(scriptRoot);
```